# Breadcrumbs with browser navigation button

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, breadcrumbs

I have following pages Home>ProductList>ProductDetail>

User can navigate to **ProductDetail** page in two ways

1. Home>ProductList>ProductDetail>
2. Home>ProductDetail

My current implementation is working fine when user is navigating using website back/forward buttons but when user navigate through the browser back/forward button then I am not able to maintain breadcrumb logic in localstorage ( because not sure how to add Eventlistener for browser back/forward button )

In other words: User can reach to "**ProductDetail**" page from multiple pages and based on that I need to show the breadcrumbs and user can navigate from browser navigation button as well as website navigation button.

Let me know if redux or any other library can help in this scenario.

My approach :

In localstorage I am maintaining an array of object when user navigate from one page to another,
it looks like
`[{name:"Home",url:"/home"},{name:"Product List",url:"/productlist"},{name:"Product Detail",url:"/productdetail}]`

Each time when user navigate to the next page I am adding an object to the localstorage and removing an object when user going back to the previous page.